# PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey only compatible on windows

Tags: c#, linux, windows, encryption, cryptography

Translating some legacy code to NET 6 running on Linux, getting an error as PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey is only compatible on windows.

Any idea how to replicate this for linux?
This is the line that's causing issues:

```
des.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("RC2", "MD5", 128, new byte[8]);
```

it returns an array of bytes
[image]

Comment: If you are not bound to PasswordDeriveBytes here and are able to switch take a look at the Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2 methods.

Comment: If you have the analyzer running either in VS or VS Code you should already receive warnings for the method you use (besides only beeing usable on windows) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca5373

Comment: does not work on net 5, getting platform not supported error